# How to get a list/array of all pixels that make up an extracted image segmentation object?

Tags: python, numpy, rgb, pixel, image-segmentation

I am a python beginner currently using pixellib to perform image segmentation for a research project. I want to find the RGB values of the pixels that comprise the extracted segment object. Below I have included some code from the pixellib tutorial on semantic segmentation (It is contained in an image attached to this post).

I want to be able to construct a list or array of pixel coordinates that correspond to the pixels that make up the image mask so I can use PIL commands to extract the RGB values. I was hoping someone could help me find a solution. (I am not familiar with what the data produced by segmask['---'] represents or how to use/manipulate it)

Sincerely,
DM

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMXTX.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack. Please post your actual code rather than pictures of it which are difficult to run. Please also share your images, or links to them. Thank you.